# Airflow CLI (Astronomer) external packages not getting updated

Tags: airflow

I am a newbie on (Astronomer) Airflow CLI. Created the image for my test project and had it run on Docker (local) successfully.

1. When I add a comment line in my dag class (on the python project); I see the classes under /usr/local/airflow/dags folder get updated immediately.
2. When I change a couple of lines in one of the python classes under /usr/local/airflow/lib/; I am not seeing it updated on the image. I have been searching for it for a few hours and nothing so far. maybe I am not using the correct jargon.

Can someone please help me? Should I include the [ /usr/local/airflow/lib/] path in a specific config file?

Thank you
Oz

Answer (score 0):

This is where the answer is. I created "plugins" folder and moved all other external classes from lib to "plugins". Sorted out the problem.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html